# Ionic.io & Firebase error on Android: Browser went offline. Killing connection

Tags: android, angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework

There seems to be a conflict at some point between the Ionic.io platform web client and Firebase. This only happens on Android (fine in the browser and on my iPhone).

Steps to recreate:

```
ionic start test-app
cd test-app
ionic platform add android
```

Install Firebase

```
bower install firebase --save
```

Add firebase script to index.html

```
<script src="lib/firebase/firebase-debug.js"></script>
```

Enable Firebase logging

```
Firebase.enableLogging(true);
```

Enable a Firebase listener on some data in the Dash controller (controllers.js)

```
.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope) {
    var ref = new Firebase('http://<YOUR-APP>.firebaseio.com');
    ref.on('child_added', function(snap) {
        console.log(snap.val());
    });
})
```

Build the Android project

```
ionic build android
```

Install the Ionic.io platform web client (ionic.service.core is injected in the app's Angular module).

```
ionic add ionic-platform-web-client
```

Emulate

```
ionic emulate android -l -c
```

I'm using a Nexus S emulator with API 23. Same result on my test Android device, a Samsung Galaxy GT-S7582 Duos running Android 4.2.2 (API 17).

Log output contains

```
p:0: Browser went offline.  Killing connection.  :4354
c:0:1: Closing realtime connection.  :4354
c:0:1: Shutting down all connections  :4354
c:0:1:0 Longpoll is being closed.  :4354
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
p:0: data client disconnected  :4354
0: onDisconnectEvents  :4354
```

When switching between the app's tabs, Firebase reconnects, then disconnects again.

The disconnects stop when 'ionic.service.core' is not injected.

Anyone experiencing the same?
Any idea how to avoid these disconnects?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Eric Bobbitt from the Ionic team, wrapping the Firebase reference declaration into an $ionicPlatform.ready() call solves this issue.

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    var ref = new Firebase('https://<YOUR-APP>.firebaseio.com');
    // Do something using ref or expose it as a service.
});
```